# Sql server aggregate function and GROUP BY Clause error

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have a query below where it compares the number of `stagingCabincrew` and `StagingCockpitCrew` columns from the staging schema and compares them to their data schema equivalent `'DataCabinCrew'` and `'DataCockpitCrew'`.

Below is the query and the results outputted:

```
WITH CTE AS
  (SELECT cd.*,
          c.*,
          DataFlight,
          l.ScheduledDepartureDate,
          l.ScheduledDepartureAirport
   FROM
     (SELECT *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LegKey
                               ORDER BY UpdateID DESC) AS RowNumber
      FROM Data.Crew) c
   INNER JOIN Data.CrewDetail cd ON c.UpdateID = cd.CrewUpdateID
   AND cd.IsPassive = 1
   AND RowNumber = 1
   INNER JOIN
     (SELECT *,
             Carrier + CAST(FlightNumber AS VARCHAR) + Suffix AS DataFlight
      FROM Data.Leg) l ON c.LegKey = l.LegKey )
SELECT StagingFlight,
       sac.DepartureDate,
       sac.DepartureAirport,
       cte.DataFlight,
       cte.ScheduledDepartureDate,
       cte.ScheduledDepartureAirport,
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN sac.CREWTYPE = 'F' THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) AS StagingCabinCrew,
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN sac.CREWTYPE = 'C' THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) AS StagingCockpitCrew,
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN cte.CrewType = 'F' THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) AS DataCabinCrew,
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN cte.CrewType = 'C' THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) AS DataCockpitCrew
FROM
  (SELECT *,
          Airline + CAST(FlightNumber AS VARCHAR) + Suffix AS StagingFlight,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Airline + CAST(FlightNumber AS VARCHAR) + Suffix
                            ORDER BY UpdateId DESC) AS StageRowNumber
   FROM Staging.SabreAssignedCrew) sac
LEFT JOIN CTE cte ON StagingFlight = DataFlight
AND sac.DepartureDate = cte.ScheduledDepartureDate
AND sac.DepartureAirport = cte.ScheduledDepartureAirport
AND sac.CREWTYPE = cte.CrewType
WHERE MONTH(sac.DepartureDate) + YEAR(sac.DepartureDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) + YEAR(GETDATE())
  AND StageRowNumber = 1 --AND cte.ScheduledDepartureDate IS NOT NULL
--AND cte.ScheduledDepartureAirport IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY StagingFlight,
         sac.DepartureDate,
         sac.DepartureAirport,
         cte.DataFlight,
         cte.ScheduledDepartureDate,
         cte.ScheduledDepartureAirport
```

The results are correct, all I need to do is add a condition in the WHERE clause where `StagingCabinCrew <> DataCabinCrew AND StagingCockpitCrew <> DataCockpitCrew`

[image]

If a row appears then we have found an error in the data, I just need helping adding this condition in the WHERE Clause because the columns in the WHERE Clause are referring to a SUM and CASE Function. I just need help manipulating the query so that I can add this WHERE Clause

Comment: I dont see the group by

Comment: I don't see why you've got the ROW_NUMBER in there either, unless you've simplified your query for this question.

Comment: show us sample data and expected output, but looks like you need to read the basic `group by` documentation first. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: @NathanKoop This is actually a bigger query and the row number is needed, I tried to shorten the length of the query rather than posting the whole code, unless you prefer the whole code?

Comment: cool, adding a `GROUP BY SabreAssignedCrew.UpdateID` under the `FROM Staging.SabreAssignedCrew` and before the closing parenthesis should work then.

Comment: @NathanKoop I think I need to change my question because I ahve realised the method I am trying will not be best practice.

Comment: You are trying to `GROUP BY UpdateID` but you dont have `UpdateID`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - I didn't see the `*` in query

Comment: `SELECT             *        ,   Airline + `

Comment: Hi everyone, I changed the question because I realised what I was trying to do would not work (well it would but I will have a really big GROUP BY clause so thought of asking of a better way of manipulating the working query to add a where clause. Thank you

Comment: Please post data as text, we cant copy/paste from image. And try to improve the query format to include some indentation.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - No I said.. I missed that `*` in query so posted wrong answer and deleted after you pointed out

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Formatted query, tbh all I need to know is how do I add the where clause to my query, I know the query results are correct, only issue like I said is I'm calling on columns which have a sum and case function so I cannot just call on their alias column names as they won't be recognised as they are all within the same query.

Comment: How can I know where to add the `WHERE` if you dont explain what are you trying to do? You can put `WHERE` in many places.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I know the condition needs to be placed in the existing WHERE Clause I have. My question is more on how do I call on the columns :)

Comment: Again, you have two `WHERE` which one? The idea is you try to make your question easy to understand, Im trying to kill zombies in my second monitor wont have enough time to try to read your mind ;)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza My apologies, I thought I removed the first where clause, it's the second where clause. The first one was just a test for something, The first WHERE clause would not exist in the final query. The second where clause will be the only where clause. Have fun with the zombie killing :)

Comment: So what problem you have when trying to add `StagingCabinCrew <> DataCabinCrew `?

Comment: It will display an error displaying they are invalid columns, this is because I have called their alias (sum functions) within the same query so it won't recognise those columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will guess you are trying to use an alias in the same query.

You **CANT** do this, because the alias wont be recognized in the `WHERE`.

```
SELECT  field1 + field2 as myField
FROM yourTable
WHERE myField > 3
```

You need to include it in a sub query

```
with cte2 as (

    SELECT  field1 + field2 as myField
    FROM yourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE myField > 3
```

or repeat the function

```
    SELECT  field1 + field2 as myField
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE field1 + field2 > 3
```

Comment: Just when you posted I was thinking do I add a second CTE, I'm assuming the GROUP BY does not go in the second CTE and is called under the final query?

Comment: Again not sure, I just answer to why you get the error. would be easy next time if you post error you get the first time in the question.

Comment: Cool, that should do the trick, enjoy killing zombies and thanks for your help